# Form do not disappear on closing java application

Tags: java, dispose, system.exit

I created a hook that excute some operation when the form is closed:

```
    Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("In shutdown hook");
            String dataCrittare = "lgt%";
            Date now=new Date();
            SimpleDateFormat dateformat = new SimpleDateFormat ("yyyyMMdd-HHmm");
            writer.println(dateformat.format(now));
            writer.flush();
            System.out.println("arrived?");
            dispose();
            System.exit(1);

        }
     }, "Shutdown-thread"));
```

It seems that the program exit, but remains the form blocked on the screen, and i have to close it brutally.
Anyone know why the form do not disappear? Thanks

Comment: I read that. wihout the program still doesn't work.. and the code
         Frame.getFrames().length
returns me that 2 frame still work (this that i want to close is the secondo form that is opened in my application), but i don't know how to close properly that forms..

Answer (score 0):

The shutdown hooks get invoked when `System.exit()` is called. You shouldn't call `System.exit()` inside your shutdown hook since the JVM **is** already on its way to termination. Inside `addShutdownHook()`, the call to `System.exit()` deadlocks at `Shutdown.exit()` (which is called from `System.exit()`). Even the comment there says:

```
        /* Synchronize on the class object, causing any other thread
         * that attempts to initiate shutdown to stall indefinitely
         */
```

**Your shutdown hook does not get called on form closing!** (Except you have some `JFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE)` or so.)

Comment: I have 
        JFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

I'm trying to resolve, but my solutions still don't work. Do you have any example code that can help me?

Comment: Please give some more details. Does your shutdown hook ever get executed? Post some minimal but complete example.